# onResize event with class object

Tags: delphi, class, object, onresize

Here's is my code:

```
type TNav = class(TPanel)
private
  procedure CMMouseEnter(var AMsg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
  procedure CMMouseLeave(var AMsg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
public
end;

type TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
public
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TNav.Create(Form1) do begin
    Parent := Self;
    Name := 'nav';
    Top := 0;
    Left := 0;
    Height := 27;
    Width := Form1.Width - 8;
    Visible := true;
    Caption := '';
  end;      
end;

procedure TNav.CMMouseEnter(var AMsg: TMessage);
begin
  Self.Top := 0;
end;

procedure TNav.CMMouseLeave(var AMsg: TMessage);
begin
  Self.Top := -23;
end;
```

Is there a way to add an onResize event for my TNav, or even to send the width/height values from the Form1?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Always put `begin` on a new line. Otherwise the trained eye doesn't see it and it will confuse the statement after the `with`/`if`/... to be a one-line statement and not an entire block of code.

Comment: @Andreas I wish you would stop pushing your style preferences upon others. While your eye may be trained to read code according to your preferences and you would miss block a like this, not everybody is so predisposed or so completely dependent on style. And in fact there are many of us who are distracted by having the begin on a new line.

Comment: @Marjan: I was almost expecting a comment on that. Yes, I will stop making these remarks.

Comment: @Andreas: thanks. It was indeed getting kind of Pavlovian wasn't it? :) +1 for your answer by the way. Good old anchors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to add a "OnResize" handler to every instance of the `TNav` (internally), or do you just want the `TNav` to display a `OnResize` event so that you can set it in the application? In the first case, just do

```
type
  TNav = class(TPanel)
  private
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var AMsg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var AMsg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  public
  end;
```

and

```
procedure TNav.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  // Do something
end;
```

In the latter case, just add

```
published
  property OnResize;
```

To access the properties of the parent form (if any), in the `TNav` class do (for example)

```
GetParentForm(Self).Width
```

By the way, are you aware of the `Anchors` property of `TPanel`? Add a `TPanel` to a form, and set `Anchors := [akLeft,akTop,akRight]` in the Property Editor. Is this something you can use?

Comment: Dayam, i had completely forgot about anchors.. that's what happens when you haven't sleep for few days. Thanks alot Andreas. Both code and reminding were great.